# Are account numbers required for international SEPA transfrers

Tags: wire-transfer, sepa

I want to carry out a wire transfer to a bank outside of the SEPA zone. The form doesn't a field for the account number. It has the account name, BIC, IBAN, bank name and address. Are account numbers not required for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The form doesn't a field for the account number. It has the account name, BIC, IBAN, bank name and address.

The abbreviation "IBAN" stands for "International Bank *ACCOUNT* *NUMBER*". It *is* the account number, so you *do* have a field for the account number. The difference compared to many traditional national account numbers is that apart from identifying your account within your institution, it also contains information about the institution and the country in a format that is internationally compatible.

Comment: See also [BIC (Bank Identifier Codes)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9362) and [IBAN (International Bank Account Number)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number).

Comment: I understand I guess I was confused becausemy bank uses an intermediary bank and the IBAN is for the intermediary bank not my local bank.